# Attempted to measure length of worms but found substantial variation, What could be problem?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I implemented contour to calculate length of worms, but found major difference in length on this Image:
[image]
Could not find the accurate length, What could be mistake here?
`contour draw` is almost accurate.
Need to know  accurate way to measure length.
Can we have any other approach to calculate length of curve structure.

```py
# Read Image    
image = cv2.imread("M2 Output.jpg")
# Convert to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# Create a binary threshold image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# Find the contours from the threshold image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
# Draw each contour on the mask
Arc=[]
Perimeter=[]
RLength=[]
for i in range(len(contours)):
         
    # Create a  mask image that contains the contour 
    cimg = np.zeros_like(binary)
    canvas = np.zeros_like(binary)
    # Draw contours,sets all value to 255 
    cv2.drawContours(cimg,contours, i, color=255, thickness=-1)
    # Apply thining to each contour image               
    thinimage = thin(cimg)
    # Access the image pixels with non zero  and create a numpy array
    x,y = np.nonzero(thinimage)
    length=reduce(lambda p1, p2: np.linalg.norm(p1 - p2), x,y)
    arclen=0
    Points=[]
    perimeter=0
    # Calculate Arc length
    for i,j in zip(y,x):
        Length = len(x)
        arclen = np.sqrt((x[1] - x[0])**2 + (y[1] - y[0])**2)
        for k in range(1, Length):
            arclen = arclen + np.sqrt((x[k] - x[k-1])**2 + (y[k] - y[k-1])**2)
    
        Points.append([i,j])
        curve = cv2.circle(canvas,(i,j), radius=0, color=(255,0,255), 
    thickness=-1)
    print('arclen',arclen)
    ctr = np.array(Points).reshape((1,-1,2)).astype(np.int32)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(ctr,False)
    print('Perimeter:',perimeter)
    print('R-Length:',length) 
    Arc.append(arclen)
    Perimeter.append(perimeter)
    RLength.append(length)
    print('Arc-Length:',Arc)
    print('Perimeter:',Perimeter)
    print('R-Length',RLength)
               
for c in contours:
    print('CPerimeter:',cv2.arcLength(c,False))
```

> Output
>
> Arc-Length: [25178.444010880532, 771.7484665460217, 397.2253967444164]
>
> Perimeter: [25177.444003224373, 770.7484695911407, 396.2253956794739]
>
> CPerimeter: 703.043718457222, 738.1147863864899, 806.4213538169861

Comment: Are you expecting all three worms to have the same length? What, specifically, is the issue with the answer that you received from OpenCV? Are you asking about why you get different answers for your various methods?

Comment: Hi @IanChu, I am expecting their length similar not equal size because all three are same type. First two perimeter measure shows drastic variation, so not satisfied. Is there any mislead?

Comment: draw *into the picture* the information you base your numbers on. specifically draw the contours. a perimeter of 25000 sounds like you got the wrong contour.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I checked all the contour drawings its exactly same as original, Do you have any suggestion on code?

Comment: great! now please show that picture (and corresponding code) here.

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, I have thinned image, if you look code it easily extract skeletonized curve. Output are:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tu_eMppcDOYrwvbVa2TN-DvO8d86fMBO/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/16oEDHztdv7q0UfrbvIUk8kh9B7k92wzx/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/16W3Z5DOT_1tWcwWGLhRkiEsH2J9TBQc_/view?usp=sharing